# XlsxWriter set_column limit rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I have a pandas dataframe that I'm writing to a excel file with `XlsxWriter`. I'm setting the cell format with

```
worksheet.set_column(first_index, last_index, None, cell_format)
```

On a few of my columns. By doing this however not only the cells with values in my excel file gets the format applied, but seemingly infinite rows get the cell format applied.

How can I limit the cell format to a set of rows?

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional formatting:

```
worksheet.conditional_format(first_index, last_index, {'type': 'no_blanks',
                                                       'format': cell_format})
```

This works if the other rows are blank. I don't know if that's the case for you.

Comment: In my case they are blank, so technically it would work, but my experience is that having many conditional format cells can significantly slow down the computer running excel. If possible I'd just like the rest of the cells to retain a default or no format.

Answer (score 1):

> By doing this however not only the cells with values in my excel file gets the format applied, but seemingly infinite rows get the cell format applied.

That is how column formatting works in Excel.

> How can I limit the cell format to a set of rows?

You can set row formatting with the `set_row()` method but from the overall question it sounds like you want to limit the formatting to a range of cells.

The only way to do that in Excel, or XlsxWriter, is to format the cells individually (apart from solutions like using conditional formatting or worksheet tables that can be applied to a range).

In order to do that with a dataframe you would need to avoid `df.to_excel()` and write the data cell by cell using XlsxWriter methods.

Comment: Interesting. This was previously what I was doing, but from what I could gather the performance difference between applying a format to each cell vs setting it on columns are vastly significant. For data frames having approximately 500x500 cells I think it would take several minutes to write. Could you perhaps suggest a way to go about it in a most effective and optimised manner?

Furthermore, in regards to using `set_row()` I think the problem would simply flip, and would then apply to an infinite number of columns which in my case is just as bad.

Comment: *"what I could gather the performance difference between applying a format to each cell vs setting it on columns are vastly significant"*. It shouldn't be. Behind the scenes XlsxWriter applies the column format to unformatted cells anyway. So the performance should be the same. Just make sure you are iterating over the dataframe efficiently (column instead of row maybe) and that you aren't creating a new format for each cell (i.e. that you reuse similar similar formats).

Comment: *"in regards to using set_row() I think the problem would simply flip"*. Yes. I meant to add that it would just shift the problem to another axis.